# swiftUI: Changing @State in onAppear crashes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to set a @State Variable if a View appears by calling a Service.
Calling the Service in `onAppear` crashes the app.
Calling the Service  in a buttons action works fine.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var dirContent : [String] = []

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List {
        ForEach(dirContent, id: \.self){
          fileName in
          Text(fileName)
        }
      }
      Button("Get Data"){self.dirContent = Service.getData()}
    }
    .onAppear{
    //self.dirContent = Service.getData2()   // Crashes!!
    }
  }
}

class Service{
  static func getData()->[String]{
    // ... get Data from somewhere
    return ["line1", "line2"]
  }

  static func getData2()->[String]{
    // ... get Data from somewhere
    return ["line4", "line5"]
  }
}
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the see why this happens, try to modify your code

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(dirContent, id: \.self){
                    fileName in
                    Text(fileName).onAppear {
                        print("item appear")
                    }
                }
            }.onAppear {
                print("list appear")
            }
            Button("Get Data"){self.dirContent = Service.getData()}
        }
        .onAppear{
            print("content appear")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dirContent = Service.getData2()
            }
        }
    }
```

the "old school" debug print shows us

```
content appear
list appear
item appear
item appear
```

Now it is clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I think I got it.
The action has to be called asynchronously.

```
.onAppear{
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.dirContent = Service.getData2()   
  }
}
```

Any Idea, why this isn't needed in the buttons action?

Comment: You already find it. Why? 1) .onAppear change the State wrapped property. 2) SwiftUI has to reevaluate its body. 3) when evaluated, the body should appear ... and the cycle continue with 1). Dispatch the change to next runloop execution will brake the cycle. .onAppear means before showing :-)